# Convert datetime.time into datetime.timedelta in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, timedelta

I am trying to convert two "durations", however I am currently receiving a `TypeError` due to one being a `datetime.timedelta` and one being a `datetime.time`:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.time() <= datetime.timedelta()
```

What is an efficient way to convert a `datetime.time` to a `datetime.timedelta`?

I have checked the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#time-objects) and there is no built-in method for conversion between these two types.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`datetime.time()` is *not a duration*, it is a point in a day. If you want to interpret it as a duration, then convert it to a duration since midnight:

```
datetime.combine(date.min, timeobj) - datetime.min
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, date, time
>>> timeobj = time(12, 45)
>>> datetime.combine(date.min, timeobj) - datetime.min
datetime.timedelta(0, 45900)
```

You may need to examine how you get the `datetime.time()` object in the first place though, perhaps there is a shorter path to a `timedelta()` from the input data you have? Don't use `datetime.time.strptime()` for durations, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I did realise it wasn't a duration, hence why I put it in quotes in the question. This works, thanks!

Comment: @R.Murray: same idea but simpler: `diff = datetime.combine(datetime.min, timeobj) - datetime.min`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: great idea, I'll just nic^Wborrow that with a small correction (`date.min` rather, when combining) :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters `combine()` accepts `datetime.min` and it is conceptually cleaner (same object in two places in the expression). Though `date.min == datetime.min.date()` and therefore `date.min` may be used.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes, `datetime.combine()` indeed accepts a `datetime` object for either argument, but I find `date.min` is clearer.

Answer (score 11):

Here's one solution I've found, though it's not necessarily efficient:

```
import datetime
x = datetime.timedelta(hours=x.hour, minutes=x.minute, seconds=x.second, microseconds=x.microsecond)
```

Where `x` is a `datetime.time` object.