# Parsing Timestamp in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have an application in which I need to parse timestamps of four different formats.

```
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.mm
MM:SS
MM:SS.mm
```

How can I write a function to parse any of these formats into a `timedelta` object?

I have tried iterating through the characters one by one and `break`ing when I see the `:`, but my code is a mess, so I would rather not have it here as a baseline.

Comment: You could use `time.strptime()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using `datetime.datetime.strptime()`:

If you don't know ahead of time which [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) your input will be in, you can try all of them wrapped in a `try`/`catch` block.

`strptime()` returns a `datetime` object, so call the `.time()` function to get only the time part. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138744/extract-time-from-datetime-and-determine-if-time-not-date-falls-within-range) for more details.

```
import datetime

def parse_timestamp(ts):
    formats = [
        "%H:%M:%S", #HH:MM:SS
        "%H:%M:%S.%f", #HH:MM:SS.mm
        "%M:%S", #MM:SS
        "%M:%S.%f" #MM:SS.mm
    ]
    for f in formats:
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, f).time()
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return None
```

Examples:

```
timestamps = [
    "12:34:56",
    "12:34:56.78",
    "34:56",
    "34:56.78"
]
for ts in timestamps:
    print parse_timestamp(ts)
```

Output:

```
12:34:56
12:34:56.780000
00:34:56
00:34:56.780000
```

Or if you know the specific format, you can use `datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, f).time()` directly.

**Update 1**

If you want to convert to `timedelta`s, you can do so using the output of `parse_timestamp()` and the [`timedelta` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
def time_to_timedelta(t):
    td = datetime.timedelta(
        seconds=t.second,
        microseconds=t.microsecond,
        minutes=t.minute,
        hours=t.hour
    )
    return td
```

Here is a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241643/convert-datetime-time-into-datetime-timedelta-in-python-3-4) that you may also find useful.